# Printing HTML with fixed header and footer

Tags: html, css

I have an html that has content over multiple pages that has to be printed. I have attached a sample below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Dynamically Generated HTML with Header for PDF</title>
<style>
/* Header styles for print */
@media print {
  .header {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     height: 50px;
    /* Adjust height as needed */
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    /* Adjust line height as needed */
    }
  }
  /* Content styles */
  .content {
    margin-top: 60px;
    /* Ensure content starts below the header */
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">Header Content</div>
<div class="content">
<!-- Your dynamically generated HTML content here -->
<p>This is a sample dynamically generated content.</p>
<!-- More content -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This has a header at a fixed position. When the html is printed to pdf the content overlaps with the header from the 2nd page onwards. The margin-top css of the content is applied only for the first page.

Even I tried setting @page css with a margin, in this case the fixed position header is also moved down by the margin. I tried with different css techniques but none of them worked. The main problem is css is getting applied only to the first printed page and not in the subsequent pages.

Comment: Maybe try this? https://plnkr.co/edit/lWk6Yd?preview

Comment: In the above solution the content is getting cut behind the background. If we remove the background color we can see the content getting overlapped with footer resulting in the same issue.

Comment: You can try setting the position of the header as `sticky` instead of `fixed`.